# Prove Product Partition is NP-complete in the strong sense

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, np-hard, partitions

I am trying to understand how to prove that the Product Partition problem is NP-complete in the strong sense. The problem is similar to the normal Partition problem, except in this case the product of the subsets is taken instead of the sum.

I have only managed to find one paper discussing the issue: [paper](https://www.academia.edu/15435582/_Product_Partition_and_related_problems_of_scheduling_and_systems_reliability_Computational_complexity_and_approximation)

This proof is very complicated and tough to understand. Could someone provide a simpler explanation of the process?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/121864/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/46488/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: What is the product partition problem?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Product partition problem : given a multi-set of integers, decide whether it can be partitioned into two parts such that the product of numbers in the first part is equal the product in second second part